Moving least square method in finite volume method
Consider a differntial equation like : $\nabla .(\nabla u)=cte$, using finite volume method we can write $\int\nabla .(\nabla u) dv =\int n.(\nabla u) dA $. Here we want to use the moving least square method (MLS) to obtain the gradient on the surface of the cell. The value of $u$ is typically approximated at cell nodes  with an equation like $u(x)=\sum N_j u(x_j)$ and then the $\nabla u= \sum \frac{\partial N_j}{\partial \mathbf{x_i}} u(x_j)$ and then the gradient is approximated at the surface using : $ \nabla = \nabla +\vec{r}\nabla (\nabla)$.
My question is why not use the MLS to approximate the value of $u$ and subsequently $\nabla u$ at the surface of the cell, in order to avoid the approximation of gradient on the surface based on the center value?

You can, in general, use any discretization methods to represent your $u$, hence, the derivatives of $u$. So you can use the meshless approach if you prefer.
Using meshes, however, is often simple to implement which is advantageous. Moreover, it works. You can also consider using "weird" designs of meshes, such as non-conforming meshes if that's what you want. But implementing non-conforming meshes can be a hassle and the question is whether you would want to go through the additional complexity of implementing that when it gives you only a little advantage (i.e., depending on your case). It's more of a weighted choice.
It's not "why not" use a particular technique but it's more like people tend to use what they know or what they are fond of.
